# Need Help handling check box values on Save that are not checked

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I have seen several posts on this and am still struggling to find a solution that works for me. I several check boxes that I need to loop through on a save. Here is what i have right now. It's an ASP page that is looping through record sets and writing out a lot of check boxes.

I've tried to use the hidden field to pass both "off" and "on" when the box is checked however its coming across on the server side as

off
on

```
    do while not rsHR.eof
    
  idPOS = rsHR.fields("emplid")
  idID = "ID" & idPOS

response.write("<TR>")

response.write("<TD nowrap align=left>&nbsp;" & rsHR.fields("EMPLID") & "</TD>")
response.write("<TD nowrap align=left>&nbsp;" & rsHR.fields("emp_name") & "</TD>")
response.write("<TD nowrap align=left>&nbsp;" & rsHR.fields("EMP_FLOOR") & "</TD>")
response.write("<TD nowrap align=left>&nbsp;" & rsHR.fields("RTO_GROUP") & "</TD>")



response.write("<TD>")
Response.Write("<INPUT type=hidden size=10 " & DisabledProperty & " id=WEEK1    name=" & idPOS & " value='off'><INPUT type=checkbox size=10 " & DisabledProperty & " id=WEEK1    name=" & idPOS & " defaultValue=" & tmp  & " value=" & tmp  & " onchange=week1(" & idID & ")>")
response.write("</TD>")

response.write("<TD>")
Response.Write("<INPUT type=hidden size=10 " & DisabledProperty & " id=WEEK2  name=" & idPOS & " value='off'><INPUT type=checkbox size=10 " & DisabledProperty & " id=WEEK2  name=" & idPOS & " defaultValue=" & tmp  & " value=" & tmp  & " onchange=week2(" & idID & ")>")
response.write("</TD>")



response.write("<TD>")
Response.Write("<INPUT type=hidden size=10 " & DisabledProperty & " id=WEEK3  name=" & idPOS & " value='off'><INPUT type=checkbox size=10 " & DisabledProperty & " id=WEEK3  name=" & idPOS & " defaultValue=" & tmp  & " value=" & tmp  & " onchange=week3(" & idID & ")>")
response.write("</TD>")
```

I was trying to handle setting the value in javascript with the onchange events but i can't get it to pass the values to my save.

```
    <SCRIPT ID=clientEventHandlersJS LANGUAGE=javascript>


var idxWEEK1 = 1;
var idxWEEK2 = 2;  
var idxWEEK3  = 3;  
var idxCHG  = 14; 
var idxEID  = 15; 
var btnSubmitPEX = document.formPEX.submitPEX;
var bsubmitingPEXform = 0 


function week1(cntl) {
  var x = document.getElementById("WEEK1").checked;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  cntl[idxCHG].value = "DIRTY";
  btnSubmitPEX.disabled = false;
}
```

Any help or ideas is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You really haven't stated what it exactly is that you are trying to accomplish. You say: *" I several check boxes that I need to loop through on a save."* Ok, but why are you looping through them? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Also, the `input` element does not have a `defaultValue` attribute.

Comment: Bassically i need the values of the check boxes to be set to a single value if they re checked or not. 

Currenlty if they are checked it's passing two values. off and on.

Comment: Or my week1 function is returning true or false. How could I take the value from that function and use it as my week 1 check box save value?

Answer (score 1):

The hidden fields aren't linked to the checkboxes, their values will be submitted whether the checkboxes are checked or not.

Consider this form

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="myfield" value="off">
 <input type="checkbox" name="myfield" value="on">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The hidden and checkbox fields have the same name - myfield - so `Request.Form("myfield")` will have a value of "off" if the box is not checked or "off,on" if it is.  If two or more values are received for the same form variable then VBScript will concatenate them with commas.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve but here's a bit of server side code which might give you some ideas.

```
Dim MyVariable, checkedstatus
If Request.Form("myfield") = "on" then
  MyVariable = "on"
  checkedstatus = "checked"
Else
  MyVariable = "off"
  checkedstatus = ""
End If

Response.Write "<form method=""post"">" & vbcrlf      
Response.Write "  <input "& checkedstatus &" type=""checkbox"" name=""myfield"" value=""on"">" & vbcrlf
Response.Write "  <input type=""submit"" value=""Submit"">" & vbcrlf
Response.Write "</form><br>" & vbcrlf
Response.Write MyVariable
```

Comment: Hi John thank you for taking time to answer my question I apologize for the vague request I am new to this. 

So i have added the server side code as you suggested and it's working to an extent. I may have missed something. 


So i added server side code for three of my check boxes and when i only select the third box i get one value passed on Submit. I would have expected to get "OFF, OFF, ON" because on only checked the thrid box. 

How can i pass the off value to the submit when the box is not checked?

Comment: A checkbox input can only have one value.  If it's checked the value is sent, if it isn't the value isn't sent.  If you want alternative values then maybe think about using radio buttons rather than checkboxes.  That's why I suggested using server side variables and assigning a value of "on" or "off" depending on whether they received a form input or not.

Comment: If you desperately want to do it client side with checkboxes then you might be able to use JavaScript to adapt your hidden fields solution. You'd need an onChange event which either removes the hidden field or changes the value of the hidden field. In the latter case you wouldn't bother collecting the value from the checkbox field itself, so would need to remove the name attributes of the checkbox fields .  I'm afraid I'm going to have to leave it to someone more proficient with JS than I am to suggest any code though!

Comment: Ok maybe I miss understand where I should have added the server side code. 

Is what you're referring to as the server side the page I'm calling  that is doing the save to the database? So that would be the server side page were I would add the code you provided to request the values from the page with the check boxes

Comment: Client side code is rendered by the client (ie the user's browser), server side code is rendered by the server and the browser never sees it.  Anything inside <% %> delimiters is server side code. a .asp file can contain both client and server side code.  The point is you can manipulate what's posted from the form with server side code before you post it to the database.  The logic is - if you receive "on" from the form then post "on" to the database, if you receive no value from the form then post "off" to the database

Comment: John- thank you so much for taking the time to respond. This has been a big help!